# Match any word in ColumnA with any word in ColumnB

Tags: r, string-matching

I've spent quite a bit of time looking around for a solution to this and haven't come across anything. Simply put lets say I have a data frame below:

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
Blue       Red
Blue       Blue
Blue       Red Blue
Blue Red  Yellow Blue
Blue Red  Yellow Blue Green
Red    Yellow Blue Green
```

I would like to return a match anytime a word is in both columns. For example a table would be returned that looks like this:

```
 ColumnA   ColumnB            Match
 Blue      Red                False
 Blue      Blue               True
 Blue      Blue Red           True
 Blue Red  Yellow Blue        True
 Blue Red  Yellow Blue Green  True
 Red       Yellow Blue Green  False
```

I've looked at using `mapply` with `grepl` and other forms of matching based on vectors and keywords but I can't seem to find anything that works for this.

Comment: Eventually splitting and intersect.

Comment: You seem to be using tab separation and that poorly transfers across the SO interface. You should instead post output of `dput(df)`

Answer (score 3):

Same idea , but I think more efficient using the fact that `strsplit` is vectorized and using `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(x,y)any(x%in%y) ,
        strsplit(dx$ColumnA, " "),
        strsplit(dx$ColumnB," "))
## [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strsplit` to split into words and then use `%in%`, one row at a time.

Data:

```
dd <- read.csv(text="
ColumnA,ColumnB
Blue,Red
Blue,Blue
Blue,Red Blue
Blue Red,Yellow Blue
Blue Red,Yellow Blue Green
Red,Yellow Blue Green")
```

Single-line matching function:

```
matchFun <- function(a,b) {
    aa <- strsplit(a," ")[[1]]
    bb <- strsplit(b," ")[[1]]
    any(aa %in% bb)
}
```

Apply to the rows:

```
apply(dd,1,function(x) { matchFun(x[1],x[2]) })
## [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. I don't fully understand it, but Thank You very much.

Comment: I'd suggest you work through the commands one at a time, looking at the intermediate output, to see what's happening ... or use `debug(matchFun)` ...

Answer (score 0):

Can also use `apply` and `intersect`.

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x){length(intersect(unlist(strsplit(x[1], " ")), 
                                           unlist(strsplit(x[2], " "))))>0})
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```